# Ansible - How to generate a command from multiple lines of lists?

Tags: ansible

I have the following  lists, generated from the output of a script.

```
 ['abc', 'abc-display-name']
 ['def', 'def-display-name']
 ['hij', 'hij-display-name']
```

I want to make use of the above output in ansible to construct and execute the following command

```
oc create project -n abc -d abc-display-name
```

I tried using the following, but its not working.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Executing the python script
      script: convert_to_list.py
      register: new_bu_list

    - name: Framing the oc commands
      shell: "oc create project -n {{item[0]}} -d {{item[1]}}"
      with_lines: "{{ new_bu_list.stdout_lines }}"
```

Not sure what am I doing wrong here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @techraf Could you please point me to the duplicate question?

Comment: I think he was referring the question in the 'linked' section of the list on the right side of this page, which seems to be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35662388/ansible-with-items-list-of-lists-is-flattening?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistaken right format of OpenShift command `oc` is:

`oc new-project abc --display-name='abc-display-name'`

If output of your `convert_to_list.py` is something like this:

`abc abc-display-name
def def-display-name
hij hij-display-name`

Then try to use:

`- name: Framing the oc commands
  shell: "oc new-project {{item.split(' ')[0]}} --display-name={{item.split(' ')[1]}}"
  with_items: "{{ new_bu_list.stdout_lines }}"`

Comment: I tried it using "-debug: msg" and I got the following


` fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "lookup_plugin.lines(abc  abc-display-name) returned 127"}`

Comment: May be you tried `with_lines` ?