# How to connect to Cisco NX-OS switch using Ansible in Ubuntu?

Tags: ansible, cisco, cisco-nxos

I want to call `ansible all -m ping` to Cisco NX-OS switch (v9.x) using Ansible 2.10.8 in Ubuntu 22.04 (Python3.10.6).

But an error occurred like below

```json
DS2 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to create temporary directory. In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the target directory. Consider changing the remote tmp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\", for more error information use -vvv. Failed command was: ( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo /tmp `\"&& mkdir \"` echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1685779849.641992-40852-58343258243109 `\" && echo ansible-tmp-1685779849.641992-40852-58343258243109=\"` echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1685779849.641992-40852-58343258243109 `\" ), exited with result 16, stdout output: Syntax error while parsing '/bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo /tmp `\"&& mkdir \"` echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1685779849.641992-40852-58343258243109 `\" && echo ansible-tmp-1685779849.641992-40852-58343258243109=\"` echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1685779849.641992-40852-58343258243109 `\" ) && sleep 0''\n\n\nCmd exec error.\n",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

I also changed `remote_tmp` variable `bootflash:/xx` but still error is occurred.

Please help me.

Change `remote_tmp` value (ansible config file)

Comment: Please read [ask] and pay attention to the [mre] section and then [edit] your question to add the missing bits. Specifically, we have no idea what your inventory looks like and which connection plugin your are using. Note that connecting to a cisco switch most probably requires using one of the plugins provided in the [`cisco.nxos` collection](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/cisco/nxos/index.html). Also note your question is on the edge of being [off-topic](/help/on-topic) on SO and is probably better suited for https://serverfault.com.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. Next time, I will remember what you told me and upload it.

Comment: you should still [edit] your question even if you have an answer to make both more useful for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

According the information provided it seems that you try to establish a SSH connection to a switch. Such devices may not have all capabilities for Python scripts.

Because of [`ping` module – Try to connect to host, verify a usable python and return pong on success](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ping_module.html) it

- "*is NOT ICMP ping, ... just a trivial test module that requires Python on the remote-node*"
- is a "*... test module, this module always returns pong on successful contact. It does not make sense in playbooks, but it is useful from `/usr/bin/ansible` to verify the ability to login and that a usable Python is configured.*"

In respect to already given comments and [Automating NX-OS using Ansible](https://developer.cisco.com/docs/nexus-as-code/#!nx-os-with-ansible/automating-nx-os-using-ansible), you may have a look into the following minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: nx-os
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
  
    ansible_connection: ansible.netcommon.network_cli
    ansible_network_os: cisco.nxos.nxos 
    ansible_become: true
    ansible_become_method: enable

  tasks:
  
  - name: Gather only the config and default facts
    cisco.nxos.nxos_facts:
      gather_subset:
      - config

  - name: Show Gathered Facts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts }}"
 
  - name: Run show version on Remote Device
    cisco.nxos.nxos_command:
      commands: show version
    register: results

  - name: Show results
    debug:
      msg: "{{ results.stdout_lines }}"
```

**Documentation**

- [Prepare execution environment](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/platform_nxos.html)
- [Gathering information](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/cisco/nxos/nxos_facts_module.html)
- [Usage of command module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/cisco/nxos/nxos_command_module.html)

**Similar Q&A**

- [Gets facts about NX-OS switches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69866639/6771046)